# How to reference certain columns or rows with Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, multiple-columns

So I am trying to reference the quantitative variables which is columns 1 to 4. I keep getting this error. What could I be possibly be doing wrong and how could I fix it?

Your help on this would be greatly appreciated.

I tried various indexing but I keep the same errors

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import randn

df_irish = pd.read_csv('iris.csv')
df_irish.columns = 
['Sepal.Length','Sepal.Width','Petal.Length','Petal.Width','Species']

x1 = df_irish.iloc[:,0:4].values
print(x1)

 ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 6 elements, new values have 5 elements
```

Comment: The problem is likely already in the `.columns = ...`. Since there are apparently *six* columns in your dataset? Probably `iris.csv` has an id column?

Comment: How do I fix this issue?

Comment: can you share part of your `.csv` file?

Comment: See answer below, and post a sample of your contents  on .csv file

Comment: I just noticed there is an extra column for numbering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the csv-file is [this one [kaggle]](https://www.kaggle.com/saurabh00007/iriscsv), then the first column is the `id` column. In that case there are *six* columns. You thus then can set the name of the columns like:

```
df_irish.columns = ['id', 'Sepal.Length','Sepal.Width','Petal.Length','Petal.Width','Species']
```

Answer (score 0):

iris.csv has an extra column.  Check for an extra comma, or an other field altogether

I reproduced the same error with these contents in iris.csv:

```
1,2,3,4,flower,4
5,6,7,8,petals,4
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have missed one column while you assign the columns' name to the `df_irish.columns`. And after fix it, I prefer to write the reference like this which is much meaningful:

```py
x1 = df_irish[df_irish.columns[0:4]].values
```

Comment: The error is already happening at the `df_irish.columns = ...` line, so changing the `x1 = ...` line will not fix this.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yeah, I point the error out in first sentence. That line of code, I think it is more meaningful than the original way of writing.